# Gmail does not respect email alias when sending emails with nodemailer

Tags: nodemailer

I have a Google Workspace account `foo@domain.com`. I have set up an email alias `noreply@domain.com`, as well as an app password.

I want to send an email as `noreply@domain.com`. However, when I do the following:

```js
  let mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'foo@domain.com',
      pass: '<password>',
    },
  });

  const resp = await mailer.sendMail({
    from: 'No Reply <noreply@domain.com>',
    to: 'some@email.com',
    subject: 'Test2'});
  console.log(resp);
```

The email sends successfully, I get a valid response:

```js
{
  accepted: [ 'some@email.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  envelopeTime: 257,
  messageTime: 390,
  messageSize: 248,
  response: '250 2.0.0 OK  ... - gsmtp',
  envelope: {
    from: 'noreply@domain.com',
    to: [ 'some@email.com' ]
  },
  messageId: '<...@domain.com>'
}
```

However, the email received still shows the sender as `No Reply <foo@domain.com>`.

I do not want to create another full user `noreply@domain.com` (this costs extra on Google Workspace): is there a way to get Gmail to use the email alias as the sender?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I literally figured this out 2 minutes after I posted the question.

For posterity, in addition to adding an alias to an account in the Admin Console (`admin.google.com`), you must also go into the Gmail settings of that account and enable the alias manually (see https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en).